# Copy Rig Animation To new Skeleton

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

Hi helpful blender gang!

I've been digging around heaps and haven't found a single consensus on how to animate one rig based on the animations from another. 
Here is what I have done:
1. Named the bones the same across both rigs
2. CTL + L, then Animation Data to apply data
3. Once I then hit play, the armature I want animated flies off and doesn't follow the animations being imported 100%.

Screenshots below:

Before CTL + L 
[image]

After adding Animation Data and hitting play
[image]
Dope Sheet shows no errors
[image]
The model I want the animation data to go into looks like it's close to working but isn't quite working 
[image]

Any advice would be great, thanks for your time!

Comment: could you please share your file before copying the animation? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/